# Firebase cloud functions inconsistent with bulk updates

Tags: node.js, http, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have my firebase cloud function in which I am calling my external api end point like this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var db = admin.database();

exports.onCheckIn = functions.database.ref('/news/{newsId}/{entryId}')
      .onCreate(event => {
        console.log("Event Triggered");
        var eventSnapshot = event.data.val();
        request.post({
              url: 'http://MyCustomURL/endpoint/',
              form: {
                data: eventSnapshot.data
             }
            }, function(error, response, body){

                console.log(response);

            });



      })
```

I am using Blaze plan and this is working completely fine. But the problem is that when I am creating bulk data (around 50 to 100 entries) the HTTP request at to my custom url is not working properly.One or two HTTP request are being skipped.

I have debugged my custom server and found out that it is not receiving missing requests from firebase. But I have also checked the cloud function logs and I can find that every event is correctly being triggered.

What could be the problem? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not returning any value from your function. This means that Cloud Functions assumes that the function is done with its work after the last statement has run. But since you're making an asynchronous HTTP call in the function, that calls may not have completed yet. Unfortunately you're not telling Cloud Functions about the fact that you have an outstanding call, so it may kill your function at any time after you return.

The solution is to return a promise that resolves after the HTTP request has completed. Since you're already including `request-promise` this is simple:

```
exports.onCheckIn = functions.database.ref('/news/{newsId}/{entryId}')
.onCreate(event => {
  console.log("Event Triggered");
  var eventSnapshot = event.data.val();
  return rp.post({
      url: 'http://MyCustomURL/endpoint/',
      form: {
        data: eventSnapshot.data
      }
  });
})
```

This is a common problem for developers new to JavaScript, or with JavaScript and Firebase, and is covered in:

- the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)
- this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html)
- this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc)

Comment: Saved my life , same logic if we are iterating with for loop for every values in the array ? Any modern rx parrlel request options best practices available ??

Comment: I have found one new way, Frank can you validate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209690/how-to-make-multiple-http-requests-from-a-google-cloud-function-cheerio-node-j